# I have not opened Google earth, yet Google Earth Pro still installed. Anything that I can do to get it off?

Tags: windows, google-earth

### OS running:

*Windows 10.*

## The Issue:

I was playing Portal 2, and I shut off my laptop to go do other things. Then I turned the laptop back on, and saw Google Earth's icon was replaced by "Google Earth Pro." Now, normally, I'd not be suspicious, because some programs install as "pro," but this is GOOGLE's own product.

Comment: Also, I opened Google Earth like 4 months ago.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Google Earth Pro a real program? It installed itself overnight, without my permission](https://superuser.com/questions/1235100/is-google-earth-pro-a-real-program-it-installed-itself-overnight-without-my-pe)

Comment: Seems to be a spate of it.

Answer (score 0):

The "**free**" edition of Google Earth was merged with Google Earth **Pro**. The normal edition of the program does no longer exist as Google Earth Pro is the only available option, with its price lowered from **$400** to ***free***. This change happened to everyone with **no** prompts. Hope my answer helped you.